# C:pipe How to write data multiple time on same pipe?

Tags: c, pipe

```
 //child process
    char buf[20];
    read(fd[0][0], buf, 20);
    printf("%s", buf);     

 //parent process
    write(fd[0][1], "12", 20);
    write(fd[0][1], "14", 20);
    write(fd[0][1], "15", 20);

 --output--
    12
    //then the program just exit. It cannot print out 14 and 15.
```

May I know that how can solve this problem? Can I make the child process waiting until it really read data from pipe?

I edited my program. And it can read all the data. However, the program just stop. It cannot continue to process. I think that it stop in the child process.

```
 //child process
    buf[6];
    int i;
    while ((i = read(fd[0][0], buf, 6)) > 0) {
         printf("%s", buf);     
    }

 //parent process
    write(fd[0][1], "12", 2);
    write(fd[0][1], "14", 2);
    write(fd[0][1], "15", 2);
    printf("done!\n");

 --output--
    121415done
  //The program just stopped in child process.
```

Comment: Your parent process is writing 20 bytes 3 times: the two chars, the null byte, and 17 garbage bytes.  The child reads only the first 20 bytes.

Comment: Why you call write(fd, "12", 20), I think should be write(fd, "12", 3) as you are sending 3 chars? And then, your function read works find as you send 20 bytes it receives this 20 bytes and print "12". Are you calling read again? To receive the rest of the messages?

Comment: No. I only called read once in the child process. How can I make sure that child can read all messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static const int BUF_SIZE = 4;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

ssize_t read_bytes;
int i;

while ((read_bytes = read(fd[0][0], buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
    printf("BUF: {\n'");

    for (i = 0; i < read_bytes; ++i) {
        if (buf[i] != '\0')
            putchar(buf[i]);
    }

    printf("'\n} : EOBUF[%d]\n", nbytes);
}

if (read_bytes < 0) {
     perror("FAIL");
}
```

**Edit:** Works bad if write size is > write data tho. Garbage at end.

- `read` [ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)
- `write` [ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)

Answer (score 0):

It did read data from the pipe.  You said "read up to 20 bytes", and it did (note that it got 17 **garbage** bytes too, and that your parent process was reading past the end of the 3-byte buffer trying to send them!).  If you want it to read more bytes, call read() again.

Comment: Actually, I will write to child with different pipe. For example, sometimes it write with fd[0][1]  or fd[1][0] etc. How can I make sure child can read all message?

Answer (score 0):

`read` will read *up to* the number of bytes you specify.  It could read less: it all depends on buffering.  To make sure you get the number of bytes you want, you'd have to use `read` in a loop:

```
//child process
#define MAXLEN 20
int total_read = 0, n;
char buf[MAXLEN + 1];
buf[MAXLEN] = 0;
p = buf;
while (total_read < MAXLEN) {
    n = read(fd[0][0], p, MAXLEN - total_read);
    if (n < 0)
        break; //error
    if (n == 0)
        break; //end of file
    total_read += n;
    p += n;
}
printf("%s", buf);
```